# CakePHP facebook logut session not destroying

Tags: php, facebook, session, logout, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and using facebook plugin from
            https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-Facebook-Plugin

I am using facebook login helper as below

```
$this->facebook->login(array('redirect' => 'facebook_login', 'label' => 'sign in via facebook', 'id' => 'fb-login')).
```

and logout helper as below

```
$this->Facebook->logout(array('redirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout'), 'label' => 'Logout')).
```

In logout action I have written this code.

```
$this->Auth->logout();
$this->redirect(Controller::referer());
```

But proble is when new user come and login, its showing old logged user data. So please help me to figure it out.

Comment: I haven't worked with Cake in a while, but there was a problem with the security setting, which would affect session handling. Check in app/config/core.php and if it's set to 'high' try a lower security setting to rule out that possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### change this below:

$this->Auth->logout();
$this->redirect(Controller::referer());

**to**

```
 $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout()):
```

Answer (score 2):

To delete cookies you need to set the exact same cookie (domain, path, name) but with an expiration that has passed - when read by the client this will cause the cookie to not be sent with the next request.

check this url https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L132

Answer (score 1):

I've used webtechnick facebook plugin in my apps several times, and logging in and out never worked the way I wanted. So now I am developing my own plugin, which uses server-side connect and can be treated as an Auth object inside CakePHP..

It's as easy as `$this->Auth->login()` and `$this->Auth->logout()`

You can check it out here: http://marianofino.github.com/Facebook-Plugin-for-CakePHP/